# Where does "vice-a-versa" come from?

Tags: latin

I believe the correct term is "vice versa", but occasionally I hear "vice-a-versa" being said. Is there any explanation for that pronunciation?

Comment: Welcome, Vortix.  A quick [search and website](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vice-a-versa) reveals all. We prefer questions with actual context and research, so they're fully fleshed out. See [How to Ask.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### *Vice* can have a disyllabic pronunciation because of its Latin origins

As vectory said, the pronunciation with four syllables didn't originate as "vice-a-versa", but as "vi-ce versa", with a non-silent *e* at the end of *vice.* Latin doesn't have silent *e*, and the phrase *vice versa* comes directly from Latin.

In the "traditional" English pronunciation of Latin, final e's in words like this were pronounced with the vowel found at the end of *lily* or *happy.* In an old-fashioned "RP" British English accent, this sound is identified as /ɪ/ (the "ih" sound of "kit"); in other accents, it is identified as /i/ (an unstressed version of the "ee" sound of "fleece"). For example, the e at the end of the word *simile,* which comes from a Latin adjective, is pronounced this way.

For some reason, *vice versa* developed a variant pronunciation with /ə/. My guess would be that the phrase was treated as a single word, and so the vowel was reduced more than a word-final vowel would be: for comparison, the word-internal "i" in the word *happily* is often pronounced as /ə/, even though in most accents it is not usual to pronounce *happy* with /ə/.

#### *Vice* also has a monosyllabic pronunciation

*Vice versa* also has what seems to be a "spelling pronunciation" where *vice* is pronounced as a single syllable /vaɪs/. This kind of spelling pronunciation (treating "e" at the end of a word as "silent e") exists for a number of other words or terms from Latin, such as *rationale,* *bona fide(s)* and *Clostridium difficile.*

Aside from spelling pronunciation, another factor that might have contributed to the use of a monosyllabic pronunciation of *vice* in *vice versa* might be influence from the French pronunciation of a prefix derived from Latin *vice.* The OED entry on this prefix says "From the 13th cent. onwards a number of these [compounds] appear in Old French, at first usually with the prefix in the form of *vis-, vi-,* but latterly assimilated as a rule to the Latin original. [...] The older examples in English, having been taken immediately from French, also present the prefix in the reduced forms *vis- (vys, viz-) and vi- (vy-),* subsequently replaced by *vice-* (also in early use *vize-*) except in *viscount* n." As far as I know, the prefix *vice-,* as in *vice-chairman,* is always pronounced as a monosyllable in English.

Comment: How often do you find yourself using _Clostridium difficile_ in casual conversation, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The e in *vice* is not silent in Latin. That sound had been pronounced, then rebracketed (like *a nadder* ~ *an adder*), and consequently fit into the common **-a-** pattern.

Answer (score 1):

According to Longman's Pronunciation Dictionary and the [OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/vice-versa?q=vice%20versa), the standard pronunciation of **vice** in **vice** versa is **vais** in AE but **vaisi** or, relevant to your question, **vaisə** in BE. Most likely, the latter variant can also be heard in other parts of the world.

(Note that English often uses the Schwa sound ə for foreign words ending in "e", even though this is generally not correct. For example, German has another Schwa sound. This distinction is missed even by dictionaries and underlies the long-standing controversy regarding the pronunciation of Porsche.)